# AngularJs - Why directives like Angular-strap and UI-Bootstrap use providers to build their compotents

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am planning to build my first complex directive, which is a component that lets the user crop and rotate an image that is provided and returns it as a Blob or Base64 string. I have been studying how other people have done it and I have used Angular-strap and UI-Bootstrap as a guide for understanding how to build efficient directives and ways to organize my code.

What has me confused is that components like the Modal and Alert use a Provider to build the component and return it, and in the directive it uses such provider to generate the content on compile, while other components like Tabs use a combination of a single controller for all the logic and a set of one or many directives and sub-directives that use such controller to build on compile.

1. So why do they use a Provider approach on some components and a Controller approach on others?
2. What are the benefits of building all the logic inside a Provider than in a Controller?

Another thing I've notices that their directives accept options through data attributes, which they parse on compile, why don't they use the directives scope to set global options?

Answer (score 0):

Writing a provider and then using it in a directive has the added benefit of being able to use the provided features programatically.